# Find gif/jpeg files with png extension and convert to png

Tags: files, find, images, imagemagick, mogrify

First command find and list jpeg/gif files with png extension.
Second command convert a file to png.

1. `find . -type f -name "*.png" | xargs -L 1 -I{} file  -i {} | grep -v 'image/png; charset=binary$'`
2. `find . -name "*.jpg" -exec mogrify -format png {} \;`

**I to combine these two commands.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec bash -c '[[ "$(file -bi {})" != "image/png; charset=binary" ]] && mogrify -format png {}' \;
```

This command will find regular files with a png extension, and then execute `mogrify -format png` on every file if the mime doesn't match "image/png; charset=binary".